# How to optimize code for iterating over dict and storing values in lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have this dictionary

```
example = {

'view_id_ga_standard_111': {'view_id': '111',
  'request_type': 'ga_standard',
  'start_date': '2019-07-01',
  'end_date': '2019-09-01',
  'status': 'New'},

'view_id_ga_standard_333': {'view_id': '333',
  'request_type': 'ga_standard',
  'start_date': '2019-07-01',
  'end_date': '2019-09-01',
  'status': 'New'},

'view_id_ga_corporate_222': {'view_id': '222',
  'request_type': 'ga_corporate',
  'start_date': '2018-07-01',
  'end_date': '2018-09-01',
  'status': 'New'}
}
```

And need to make a pandas df out of it, so it looks like this

```
    id  request_type start_date  end_date   request_id  status

2   111 ga_standard  2019-07-01 2019-09-01  1           New
3   333 ga_standard  2019-07-01 2019-09-01  2           New
5   222 ga_corporate 2018-07-01 2018-09-01  3           New
```

I have ended up with this function

```
def ga_make_request_types(params):
    vids = []
    rtypes = []
    sdates = []
    edates = []
    js = []
    statuses = []
    j = 0


    for k,v in data_for_config.items():
        j = j + 1
        view_id = v['view_id']
        vids.append(view_id)
        request_type = v['request_type']
        rtypes.append(request_type)
        start_date = v['start_date']
        sdates.append(start_date)
        end_date = v['end_date']
        edates.append(end_date)
        status = v['status']
        statuses.append(status)
        js.append(j)

    df = pd.DataFrame(zip(vids, rtypes, sdates, edates, js, statuses), columns=['id', 'request_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'request_id', 'status'])

    return df
```

But it is quite ugly, is it possible to shorten the code with list comprehensions?

I have tried like this

```
for k,v in data_for_config.items():
   vids = [v['view_id'] for v in k]
```

and like this

```
for k,v in data_for_config.items():
   vids = [v['view_id'] for v in data_for_config[k]]
```

But it throws an error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Why is it that people always use variable names which don't say anything to anybody except the original coder (and this probably just within some days or at most months after writing the code)?  What's a `j`?  What's `rtype`, `edate`, and `vids`?  You guys should be forced to code in a language which doesn't use `return` but `rtn`, not `for` but `fr`, not `.append` but `.apd`.

Comment: how is `request_id` determined? does the order matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example).T
```

Output:

```
                            end_date  request_type  start_date status view_id
view_id_ga_corporate_222  2018-09-01  ga_corporate  2018-07-01    New     222
view_id_ga_standard_111   2019-09-01   ga_standard  2019-07-01    New     111
view_id_ga_standard_333   2019-09-01   ga_standard  2019-07-01    New     333
```

Edit:

I'm not sure how `request_id` is determined, but you could do something like:

```
df['request_id'] = range(1, df.shape[0] + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the dict and Transpose  DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(example).T.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'view_id':'id'})

    id  request_type  start_date    end_date status
0  111   ga_standard  2019-07-01  2019-09-01    New
1  333   ga_standard  2019-07-01  2019-09-01    New
2  222  ga_corporate  2018-07-01  2018-09-01    New
```